# Mirror Screen for Capture Card

Tags: video-capture

I bought the Hauppauge Colossus cap card for its HDMI input. (I don't have the pc specs to run a real capture card.)

I will be recording my laptop's gaming using my desktop (with cap card).

My Question:
Will I need to also buy a HDMI splitter or is it possible to mirror my screen. Or will that be too much for my laptop to handle?

I guess the real question is: How much does mirroring your screen impact the video card's performance?

**Edit**
My laptop has one HDMI output on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After doing some more research on the subject I've found that mirroring your display will have a serious impact on your video cards performance.

So... if your computer is barely playing the game on high settings, it's not possible.

Comment: What about if you watch your game on the desktop's monitor through the capture software and disable the laptop's monitor.  It would introduce a bit of lag though.